# "No property" error while declaring superclass for Spring Data repositories

Tags: spring, spring-data

I have a simple webapp that uses few spring components - **Spring Boot**, **MVC** and  **Spring Data** for persistence management (everything is written in **Groovy** build up with **Gradle**).
I am trying to add some common logic for all repositories as it is described in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories). I created the following artifacts:

`GenericObjectRepository` which is an interface defining my common method:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
interface GenericObjectRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    String sharedCustomMethod(String name)
}
```

`GenericObjectRepositoryImpl` implementing above interface:

```
class GenericObjectRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements GenericObjectRepository<T, ID> {

    EntityManager entityManager

    GenericObjectRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(domainClass, entityManager)

        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    String sharedCustomMethod(String name) {
        "Hello ${name}"
    }
}
```

and finally the repository (with some random data-specific method)

```
@Repository
interface MarketingClientRepository extends GenericObjectRepository<MarketingClient, Long> {
    List<MarketingClient> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

The problem is that everytime I start the application, and Spring tries to instantinate `MarketingClientRepository`, i get the following Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'marketingClientRepository': Invocation of init method failed;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property shared found for type MarketingClient!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:359)
...
```

It seems to me that Spring Data is trying to parse my method (`sharedCustomMethod`), extracting the `shared` part and tries to apply all the magic it does to every other Repository interface method (tries to access `shared` property on my business object - which obviously does not exist).

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT 1:**

I added the FactoryBean as it is said in step 3, but I failed to compile it. I don't know if it's something wrong with generics (I admit that this construction is quite complicated for me). The class code is as follows:

```
class GenericRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        new GenericRepositoryFactoryBean(entityManager)
    }

    private static class GenericRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private EntityManager entityManager

        GenericRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityManager)

            this.entityManager = entityManager
        }

        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            new GenericObjectRepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) metadata.getDomainType(), entityManager)
        }

        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            GenericObjectRepository.class
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
/.../GenericRepositoryFactoryBean.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class T 
 @ line 14, column 60.
   yBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, 
                                 ^

/.../GenericRepositoryFactoryBean.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class I 
 @ line 14, column 63.
   an<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I e
                                 ^

2 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically miss step 3 in the steps required to make this work described in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories).

As the process is rather awkward, I've filed a [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-542) to simplify this process.

Comment: Hello Oliver, Thanks for your answer. I noticed that this is a required step after I posted my question. I tried to create the FactoryBean but at the moment I failed (I think something is wrong with generics) :( I updated my question, do you have any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: The test cases use that declaration: `class JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends JpaRepository<Object, Serializable>> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T, Object, Serializable> { … }`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. I applied the change and now it compiles without any errors (I will also take few more improvements from test cases and rewrite my code a bit). One more question, I understand I have to move to standard XML configuration and use `<jpa:repositories base-package="..." factory-class="..." />` element to make it all work? At the moment my app is configured with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and annotations.

Comment: The `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation also has a `repositoryFactoryBeanClass` attribute, so you can use that to point to your custom class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, it works great. I think you saved me a lot of time :)